# Have a single screen on a second monitor on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: multiple-monitors, workspaces

My problem is that i have 2 monitors, and i would like to have the second one to have an independent screen from the first one, so that way i could left a diagram on that one(Or an Excel with data), while i work on multiple screens on the first one, but Ubuntu only have 2 options, or the 2 monitors have different screens with the same workspace(Meaning that if you change of workspace, the other one also changes), or you have a mirror screen with the same on both, with neither of the two being what i want.

Is there a way to do this on native Ubuntu, or is there a third party software for this?

Comment: Try Right-Clicking the title bar of the application and choose "Always on Visible Workspace"

Comment: Ok, i didn't know that option existed, not the answer, but actually an excellent alternative. Thanks a lot!

Comment: GNOME now is like that; and Cinnamon has an option to be like that; but only these two.